# Esconder somente as linhas filhas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
<tabele>
   <thead>
      <tr>Codigo</tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr>exemplo</tr>
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr>exemplo</tr>
    <tbody>
</tabele>
```

Tenho um script feito em JQuery que a cada click de acordo com a classe "click-show-hide-tr" ele mosta a proxima "tr" veja o script logo abaixo:

```
var toggleTable = (function () {
    var init = function(){
        $(".toggle-table tbody").on('click', '.click-show-hide-tr', function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
        });
    };

    return {
        init:init
    }
})();

toggleTable.init();
```

Só que eu quero esconder todas as linhas secundária ao clicar novamente na primeira linha sem afetar as outras linhas que estão escondidas ou não Exemplo:

```
<tabele>
   <thead>
      <tr>Codigo</tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
       /**
        * Essa é a linha Principal supondo que as linhas secundarias
        * estejam à mostra ao clicar nela de novo 
        * quero esconder todas elas sem afetar 
        * as outras linhas
        */
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr>exemplo</tr>

        /**
         * Esse é outra linha Principal com suas linhas secundarias
         * Não posso afetar nada daqui para baixo
         */
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr class='click-show-hide-tr'>exemplo</tr>
       <tr>exemplo</tr>
    <tbody>
</tabele>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente sua seleção não está funcionando corretamente.

A função **.closest("tr")** procura o elemento "tr" antecessor, enquanto **.next()** procura todos os elementos irmãos sucessores, ou seja, o toggle está sendo aplicado para todas as linhas abaixo dos itens que possuem a classe '.click-show-hide-tr'.

Exemplo **.next()**: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_traversing_next

Uma maneira de solucionar isso pode ser adicionando uma classe 'selecionado' ao item clicado.
A partir dela você verifica quais linhas devem ser escondidas. Tente fazer assim:

```js
$(".click-show-hide-tr").click(function(){

  // Se o item clicado nao estiver selecionado
  if(!$(this).hasClass("selecionado")) {

    // Adiciona a classe selecionado ao item
    $(this).addClass("selecionado");

    // Mostra as linhas secundarias apenas do item selecionado
    $(".click-show-hide-tr.selecionado").next().fadeIn();
  } 
  else {
    // Esconde as linhas secundarias apenas do item selecionado
    $(".click-show-hide-tr.selecionado").next().fadeOut();

    // Remove a classe selecionado do item
    $(this).removeClass("selecionado");
  }
});
```

Comment: Ainda estou tendo problemas, quando clico em qualquer outra linha todas as linhas filhas são escondidas...

Comment: tente usar `$(".selecionado tr:first-child");` em vez de `$(".click-show-hide-tr.selecionado").next();`

Comment: Consegui aqui deu certo !